# Java FX - Merge Sort and Bubble Sort Animation Issues

Tags: java, sorting, animation, javafx, computer-science

I've been working on a Java FX application. It's designed to be a teaching tool for the A-Level AQA Computer Science Course. I'm currently working on the visualisation for the sorting algorithms that are in the course. However I'm having issues with the animations. I use a sequential transition. The sequential transition then executes the parallel transitions which execute the 2 translate transitions for swapping 2 elements in an array. In theory this should work perfectly. However when I execute the transitions, the positioning of the elements is strangely affected. I've included the code and images to show before and after. Please help me.

Images:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYMSg.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhAij.jpg

Code:

Sorting Class:

```
public boolean BubbleSortWrapper() {
    if (Array.size() > 1) {

        Animations = new SequentialTransition();
        BubbleSort();
        Animations.play();

        return true;
    }
    return false;
}




private void BubbleSort() {
    //O(n^2) - BubbleSort using CompletedFlag implimentation

    boolean CompletedFlag = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < Array.size() && CompletedFlag; i++) {
        CompletedFlag = false;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < Array.size(); j++) {
            if (Array.get(i).element.compareTo(Array.get(j).element) > 0) {       
                Element<Type> Temporary = Array.get(i);
                Animations.getChildren().add(Animation.Swap(GetStackPaneFromElement(Array.get(i).element), GetStackPaneFromElement(Array.get(j).element), GetXPosition(i), GetXPosition(j)));

                Array.set(i,Array.get(j));
                Array.set(j, Temporary);

                Array.get(i).index = i;
                Array.get(j).index = j;

                CompletedFlag = true;      
            }
        }
    }

}

private double GetXPosition(int Index){
    return (StartX + (Index * (ElementWidth + ElementGap)));
}
```

Animation Class:

```
public static ParallelTransition Swap(StackPane ElementPane1, StackPane ElementPane2, double X1, double X2) {   
    return new ParallelTransition(
            Move(ElementPane1, X2), 
            Move(ElementPane2, X1)                    
    );
}

public static TranslateTransition Move(StackPane ElementPane, double X) {
    TranslateTransition Transition = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(900) , ElementPane);
    Transition.setToX(X);
    return Transition;
}
```

Comment: I can't at a glance see anything immediately wrong. I'd suggest including all the code that adds the StackPanes. I have taken your basic methods and implemented the rest from scratch and it seems to work fine. However, as someone teaching CS please use standard Java naming convention (i.e. methods beginning with lower case letters and using camelCase). Going against standard naming conventions makes your code much harder to read and immediately promotes bad practice to your students.

Comment: My students prefer CapWorld from Python's PEP 8. Which is why I am using their preferred conventions. Personally I prefer camelCase. However I disagree with your opinion that decreases readability. Is it possible for you to upload your implementation?

Comment: this isn't Python and it just makes seasoned Java programmers confused. But I won't argue about it. Here's the implementation I cobbled together: [BubbleSortVisualization.java](https://pastebin.com/0Q9in0wu)

Comment: just updated the bubble sort algorithm in case you have already checked it as it was erroneous.

Comment: This is a good SO question, but you may also be interested in checking out [cseducators.se].